# Does convergence of integral series and all derivative series imply convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, convergence-divergence

Let $f_n : \mathbb R \to \mathbb [0,\infty)$ be a sequence of smooth functions such that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{\mathbb R} f_n(x) dx$$
is convergent. Further, we have that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n^{(k)}(x)$$
converges for every $x \in \mathbb R$ and every $k\in \mathbb N$.
Does this imply that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$$
converges for all $x\in\mathbb R$?

Note that for me $0 \notin \mathbb N$. See also [my last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4190820/131887) where the question is solved in the case where we restrict $k$ to be $2$.

Comment: Just one remark: If instead of "every $k \in \Bbb N$", you restrict yourself to "$k \leqslant N$" for some fixed $N \in \Bbb N$, then you can get a counterexample. The construction in the answer of your last question can be modified to get an appropriate sequence $\exp(- g(n) x^k)$ that works.

Answer (score 1):

We modify the choice of the function in the linked answer. The idea is to use a smooth function $g$ with $g^{(k)}(0)=0$ for any $k\geq 0$. One such function is
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases} \exp(-1/x^2) &\mbox{ if } x\neq 0\\
0 &\mbox{ if } x=0.\end{cases}
$$
Let
$
h(x)=\exp(-x^2g(x)).
$
Then we have
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} h(x)dx = c \in (0,\infty).
$$

Let $f_n(x)= h(n^2x)$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(0)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1=\infty$ and
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n(x) dx = \frac c{n^2}.
$$
This gives
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n(x) dx 
$$ is convergent.

For any $k\geq 1$, $f_n^{(k)}(x)$ is a finite linear combination of the terms with $g$ or higher derivatives multiplied by $\exp(-n^4 x^2 g(n^2x))$. Thus, by $g(x)\asymp 1$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$ and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n^{(k)}(x)
$$
is convergent for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What do you mean by "$g(x) \asymp 1$ as $x \to \infty$"?

Comment: There is $K>0$ such that $1/2 \leq g(x) \leq 1$ whenever $x\geq K$.